# Terms for different types of clouds before 1770?

Tags: terminology

Using Google Books I couldn't find any reference to cumulus clouds before 1772. What terms were used for the different types of clouds before 1772, if there were specific terms?

Comment: What research have you done on the history of cloud classification? In particular, is the Wikipedia entry on Luke Howard any help? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Howard

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen Luke Howard's work was published in 1803. I'm interested in how different clouds were referred to in the 1600's, but I assumed any information that predates 1773 would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, but generally on this site it's expected that you show that you've done some previous research; you're more likely to get an answer if you can summarise what you know so far. So can you add what research you have done? For example, beyond a simple google search have you consulted any books on the history of science? And what you have found out so far?

Comment: What reference from the year 1772 did you find to "cumulus clouds"? If you can give us more detail, it would help us all to track down more information.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm actually trying to find this reference to 1772 but Google Books doesn't return anything at all for me before Howard, so it would really help to know which references you have found before Howard.

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen I now see the results I got were a mistake, there is no result before 1800.